# How do I suppress the bluetooth pairing request dialog in Android(api 19)?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm using setPin() from api 19 to automatically pair with a bluetooth device.  I do this via broadcast receiver...checking for pairing requests, then automatically pairing.  The reason for this is to keep the user from having to re-enter a pin once they've changed it in my app.

Is there a way to suppress the notification/dialog of the bluetooth pairing request?  My code changes the PIN on the phone correctly and connects to the device, so that part is not a problem.  I just want to get rid of the dialog/popup so users aren't confused.  I don't mind if it pops up for a second, as long as it automatically gets closed.

```
    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
        if (btDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST.equals(action)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX PAIRING REQUEST RECEIVED XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

            int bondState = btDevice.getBondState();

            if (bondState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE || bondState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING) {                  
                String pinString = settings.getString("com.hiqautomation.iopener.pin", null);

                byte[] pinBytes = pinString.getBytes();
                btDevice.setPin(pinBytes);
            }
        }
    }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you have any luck with this?
I have done the same thing...the below should help....

```
    Method m = bt_device.getClass().getMethod("cancelBondProcess", (Class[]) null);
    m.invoke(bt_device, (Object[]) null);
```

Out of interest, how did you hide the Soft Keyboard when entering the pin. This is the issue im currently playing with at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25290319/android-how-to-disable-soft-keyboard-during-bluetooth-pairing

Mat

Comment: We actually moved on to Bluetooth 4.0 and a whole new set of problems.  I never did get the pairing to be suppressed.

Answer (score 0):

I use `Xamarin` but there should be a java equivalent.

I call the method `InvokeAbortBroadcast()` after setting the pin.

```
 Device.SetPin(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pin));
 InvokeAbortBroadcast();
```